# The pirate world's rules of distribution

Tags: code-golf

There is an existing "game" where pirates rationally divide gold coins according to certain rules. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_game):

> There are 5 rational pirates, A, B, C, D and E. They find 100 gold coins. They must decide how to distribute them.
>
> The pirates have a strict order of seniority: A is superior to B, who is superior to C, who is superior to D, who is superior to E.
>
> The pirate world's rules of distribution are thus: that the most senior pirate should propose a distribution of coins. The pirates, including the proposer, then vote on whether to accept this distribution. In case of a tie vote the proposer has the casting vote. If the distribution is accepted, the coins are disbursed and the game ends. If not, the proposer is thrown overboard from the pirate ship and dies, and the next most senior pirate makes a new proposal to begin the system again.
>
> Pirates base their decisions on three factors. First of all, each pirate wants to survive. Second, given survival, each pirate wants to maximize the number of gold coins each receives. Third, each pirate would prefer to throw another overboard, if all other results would otherwise be equal. The pirates do not trust each other, and will neither make nor honor any promises between pirates apart from a proposed distribution plan that gives a whole number of gold coins to each pirate.

## Challenge

Take as input an integer `n`, 1<=n<=99, where `n` is the number of pirates - and output the distribution of coins, starting with the first pirate.

### Test cases (first line is input; the second output):

```
1
100

2
100 0

3
99 0 1

5
98 0 1 0 1
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: I think this was asked before, but I wouldn't know where to find it.

Comment: @feersum http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54235/famous-greedy-pirates-problem (deleted)

Comment: Args[0]. Java now has a reason to use this.

Comment: I wouldn't remove it just yet, but the challenge is rather easy. You basically have to print `X, 0, 1, 0, ...`, where `X` is chosen so that the sum is 100.

Comment: Why limit `n < 100`? Over-staffed, under-gilded pirate ships need distributional help as well.

Comment: Surely _rational_ pirates would simply distribute `100/n` coins to each pirate.

Comment: @Neil that is a terrible idea.  If that is what "rational" pirates do, then all pirate other than A will try to kill A so that they get $100/(n-1)$ instead.  This will quickly kill off everyone except the last two pirates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
R%2ḊµSȷ2_;
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UiUy4biKwrVTyLcyXzs&input=&args=NQ) or [verify all test cases at once](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UiUy4biKwrVTyLcyXzsKw4figqw&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNQ).

#### How it works

For input **n**, the task boils down to creating the list **x, 0, 1, 0, …** of length **n** whose sum is **100**.

```
R%2ḊµSȷ2_;  Main link. Input: n

R           Yield [1, 2, ..., n].
 %2         Replace each integer by its parity. Yields [1, 0, 1, 0, ...].
   Ḋ        Dequeue; remove the first 1. This yields the list a = [0, 1, ...].
    µ       Begin a new, monadic link. Argument: a
     S      Compute the sum of a.
      ȷ2_   Subtract the sum from 100. (ȷ2 is 1e2 in Python syntax)
         ;  Prepend the difference to a.
```

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:([-n/2+101]+[0,1]*n)[:n]
```

Computes the first value, appends some `0, 1, 0, 1...`, truncates to length `n`.

Note that `-n/2+101` can't be shortened to `101-n/2` because unary and binary `-` have different precedence: the former is parsed as `(-n)/2` and the latter as `101-(n/2)`.

Recursion was much longer (45):

```python
f=lambda n,i=100:1/n*[i]or f(n-1,i-n%2)+[n%2]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 12 bytes

```
:2\ts_101+l(
```

This uses [current version (9.2.2)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/9.2.2) of the language/compiler, which is earlier than this challenge.

#### Example

```
>> matl :2\ts_101+l(
> 5
98  0  1  0  1
```

#### Explanation

```
:         % implicitly input number "n". Generate vector [1, 2, ..., n]
2\        % modulo 2. Gives [1, 0, 1, ...]
ts        % duplicate and compute sum
_101+     % negate and add 101
l(        % assign that to first entry of [1, 0, 1, ...] vector. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, 13 bytes

```
+-100sJ%R2tQJ
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B-100sJ%25R2tQJ&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A99&debug=0).

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>62</s> 58 bytes

EDIT: Glad I made it a one-liner. But I lose for Python. Therefore, this is just for reference. Thanks @Zgarb

```
def x(i):n=[~j%2for j in range(i)];n[0]=101-sum(n);print n
```

It takes the input, creates a list pf parity of all numbers from 1 to i. Then sets the first element in i to 101-sum(n) and prints.

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/rH9PDw)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 45 bytes

```
a=>[...Array(a)].map((x,y)=>y?--y%2:202-a>>1)
```

Thanks to @Neil for 1 byte saved!

Comment: `202-a>>1` saves a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## , 14 chars / 26 bytes

```
⩥ï⒨?‡$%2:ỉ-ï»1
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=5&code=%E2%A9%A5%C3%AF%E2%92%A8%3F%E2%80%A1%24%252%3A%CB%9C%E1%B9%A5-%C3%AF%2F2)</kbd>

Not bad, but not good either...

## Explanation

```
⩥ï⒨?‡$%2:ỉ-ï»1 // implicit: ï=input, ṥ=101
⩥ï⒨            // map over a range [0,ï) and return:
    ?‡$%2       // (if mapitem>0) then ($-1) mod 2
         :ỉ-ï»1 // (else) 202-ï>>1
                // implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Seriously, <s>23</s> 17 bytes

**EDIT**: Thanks @quintopia

```
,R`2@%`M;Σ2╤u-0(T
```

Uses the same approach as my Python answer, but I do the modulo 2 using mapping, and several times, I rotate my stack.

**Explanation**:

This code pushes input (I will call it `i`). Next pushes `range(1,i+1)` and makes a function.  Then pushes 2, rotates stack, and finally takes modulo.

Next, map this function onto the range iterable. This gives the parity of each element in the list.

Finally, duplicates the stack, sums the parity list, push 2, 10^2, and 100+1, and subtracts the sum (let me call this value `n`). Next the code pushes 0, rotates the stack by 1, and sets the list's index 0 element to n. The resulting list is implicitly printed.

Comment: This should be no more than 17 bytes: ``,R`2@%`M;Σ2╤u-0(T``

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 14 bytes

Yet another challenge where I find myself wishing for a built-in I had just considered adding...

```
1oU mv u#Ê-UÁ1
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=MW9VIG12IHUjyi1VwTE=&input=NQ==)

```
1oU mv u#Ê-UÁ1  // Implicit: U = input integer
1oU             // Create the range [1, U).
    mv          // Map each item to 1 if even, 0 otherwise.
       u        // Unshift (add to the beginning of the array)
        #Ê-UÁ1  //  the char code of Ê (202), minus U >>> 1 (floor of U / 2).
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actionscript 3, 87 bytes

`function x(n){var l=[],i=1;for (l[0]=int(101-n/2);i<n;){l[i]=++i%2;}return l.join(" ")}`

It's not the best golfing language, but I enjoy posting as3 answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes (Non-comp)

```
<LÈDOTns-s)˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/jc7jDxT8kr1i3WPP0nP//LU0B)

Comment: `s)˜` can be `¸ì`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ov hL-Uz
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=b3YgaEwtVXo&input=NQ)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
$,=$";@"=map{$i++%2}2..<>;say 100-(@">>1),@"
```

Need the following perlrun options `-E`

```
$ perl -E'$,=$";@"=map{$i++%2}2..<>;say 100-(@">>1),@"'<<<5
98
0
1
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
:?100-(a-1)'\`2[2,a|?b%2
```

Explanation

```
:               Get command line parameter, assign to 'a'
                Determine the part of the treasure for the crew:
      (a-1) \ 2 Integer Divide 'a'-1 by 2. The -1 compensates for even cases.
           ' `  Make \ a direct command for QBasic instead of substituting it for ELSE.
?100-           Print 100 coins, minus the crew-share --> Captain's booty.
[2,a|           FOR b=2; b <= a; b++; ie for every other crew member
?b%2            Give every odd crewman a coin.
                [FOR loop implicitly closed by QBIC]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [13 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
¾*†^…wu½►♦ž]#
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=WzEwMS06XjotX3shfS0+&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTA=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `[101-:^:-_{!}->`

```
[           Begin sequence
          --First entry--
     101    Literal `101`
 -          Subtract
   :^       Ceiling
     :-     Halve
       _    A variable ≡ STDIN
          --Other entries--
    {       Block
      !     Boolean NOT
        _   Implied; last entry
    }       End block
  ->        To final length of
    _       Implied
]           End sequence; implied
```

I am pretty sure this can be golfed further, but I'm leaving it here for now.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
Ṡ:o`-100Σt↑İ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9odXNr///huaA6b2AtMTAwzqN04oaRxLDCrP///zU)